# Select vertex on a zero-angled corner of a quad face

Tags: mesh, selection-tools

Sorry, I don't know how to name these vertices properly (green highlighted).

[image]

They belong to a face which is technically a quad, but with one zero-angle corner.

Selecting by `amount of connected edges` or `amount of adjacent faces` includes corner vertices, which is unacceptable, because they define shape of mesh.

Any idea how to select them automatically? Or dissolve.

Comment: Are these always border vertex, near the edge of the mesh?

Comment: In my case yes, always border

Comment: In that case you could probably easily do away with checker deselect, if they are always one apart or in a repeating pattern

Comment: Checker deselect is working only within connected geometry. AFAIK it can't be used on all selected "mesh islands" inside one object.

Comment: True, it requires an active vertex, since there can be only one it only works in one mesh island at a time. Try hiding the rest of the mesh, it may give you a few more options

Comment: On my monitor, I can't tell if there are faces, or only connected line segments.  Which is it?

Comment: There are faces, just wireframe mode